# How Do I Recover Formatted Mac hfs+ Partition?

Tags: partition, windows, disk-format

I was installing Win8 on a Mac where I got the error that I can because of GPT disk I dont know what MAC I have but the Mainboard is number is Apple Mac 942859f58194171B. I tried formatting the specific partition **not the disk** but unfortunately, I formatted the disk which contained my MAC OS together with the Recovery. I am now stuck in windows and I don't have the MAC Recovery Disk. What can I do to recover my MAC OS and potentially recovery in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (depending on your model) is to do an Internet Recovery. You can do this by holding Command+Option+R while your computer boots. You will get a globe and will either ask you to connect to Wifi or if you are connected to ethernet you will just see a progress bar. After it downloads it will bring you to the recovery partition and you can re-partition your HDD and such.

Comment: Thank you for replying @Alex. I unfortunately don't have the MAC keyboard for this pc. However, I have another MAC OSx 10.8.4 which has a Keyboard and Mouse. Will it work with this one?

Comment: @CheddieMerai If you have a Windows keyboard you would be pressing Control+Alt+R instead. Command key = Control and Option key = Alt key.

Comment: Unfortunately. That does not work. It goes straight into Windows. However, When I hold **Alt** it goes to a screen where I select the disk to boot with.

Comment: Do you know what kind of Mac you have? (Macbook Pro, iMac, Mac Mini)

Comment: It's an iMac 27inch.

Comment: Does it have a DVD drive? If so your honest to go best bet is to call Apple tech support and tell them you lost your OS X install CD and they will ship you out a new one (sometimes they do charge you for it though). If it is a thinner model the Internet Recovery should work. Internet Recovery only works on 2011 models and newer though as an FYI.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank for your help. I understand. Mind [checking this out](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154500/how-do-i-fix-the-audio-in-windows-8)

Comment: Sure, since I dont have enough rep to comment on it could you tell me the serial number for the computer? Since its an iMac it should be engraved on the bottom of the stand. This will help me know what exact model you have and how to help.

Comment: Got any rep now? Serial # is **C02G8094DHJP**