# How Do I fix The Audio in Windows 8?

Tags: macos, audio, driver, windows

I have Windows 8 installed on my MAC but I don't have sound. The Internal speakers are not detected by Win8. In the charm, it show this; **No speakers or headphones.**

[image: no speaker]

and in Driver manager The High definition audio controller is not working.

[image: driver]

In Properties

[image: properties]

And driver

[image: driver properties]

Can anyone assist me with this issue?

**Note:**  [I have no access to my MAC partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154493/how-do-i-recover-formatted-mac-hfs-partition)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. I would just like to point out to the moderators that this is in the wrong section. Flagged as "A lot of Duplicates" and "Needs Moderator Attention"

Comment: Actually i am also using the same Model. I too facing the same issue. My audio drive is not working same as shown in the pictures. Did anyone have any idea to fix this? Pls post here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the model of your computer (iMac 27" Mid 2011) you should be using the drivers located at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720 on your copy of Windows 8/8.1.

Comment: Presently downloading. I'll give it a try.